# Liquification of gas

Tags: matter, gas

During the process of liquification  of gas the volume of gas suddenly decreases in the region BC.  what happens in the gas which causes such an abrupt change in its volume at a constant pressure? [image: Liquification of gas.]

Comment: What are your ideas with regard to answering the question?

Comment: @Farcher, I possibly think that the gas suddenly  liquefies which leads to decrease in its volume at a constant pressure but my question is, what makes gas suddenly change its phase.

Comment: It's not any more "sudden" as in there is no time axis on the graph. 
The intermolecular bonds pull the molecules closer together when they form. Whereas at higher pressure (and temperature) they are already closer. Other effects too.